# parsing CSV to pandas dataframes (one-to-many unmunge)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, panels

I have a csv file imported to a pandas dataframe. It probably came from a database export that combined a one-to-many parent and detail table. The format of the csv file is as follows:

```
header1, header2, header3, header4, header5, header6

sample1, property1,,,average1,average2
,,detail1,detail2,,
,,detail1,detail2,,
,,detail1,detail2,,

sample2, ...
,,detail1,detail2,,
,,detail1,detail2,,
...
```

(i.e. `line 0` is the `header`, `line 1` is `record 1`, `lines 2` through `n` are details, line n+1 is record 2 and so on...)

What is the best way to extricate (renormalize?) the details into separate `DataFrames` that can be referenced using values in the `sample#` records? The number of each subset of details are different for each sample.

I can use:

```
samplelist = df.header2[pd.notnull(df.header2)]
```

to get the starting index of each sample so that I can grab samplelist.index[0] to samplelist.index[1] and put it in a smaller dataframe. Detail records by themselves have no reference to which sample they came from, so that has to be inferred from the order of the csv file (notice that there is no intersection of filled/empty fields in my example).

Should I make a list of dataframes, a dict of dataframes, or a panel of dataframes?

Can I somehow create variables from the sample1 record fields and somehow attach them to each dataframe that has only detail records (like a collection of objects that have several scalar members and one dataframe each)?

Eventually I will create statistics on data from each detail record grouping and plot them against values in the sample records (e.g. sampletype, day or date, etc. vs. mystatistic). I will create intermediate Series to also be attached to the sample grouping like a kernel density estimation PDF or histogram.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that the first `column` seems to be empty unless it's a new `sample` record to [`.fillna(method='ffill')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then [`.groupby('header1')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to get all the separate groups. On these, you can calculate statistics right away or store as separate `DataFrame`. High level sketch as follows:

```
df.header1 = df.header1.fillna(method='ffill')
for sample, data in df.groupby('header1'):
     print(sample) # access to sample name
     data = ... # process sample records
```

Comment: Your example allows me to get at my data easily. Forward fill was very helpful. I've got your example working, only now each pass of the `for` loop must save `sample` and `data` into some new object. I was hoping for two new dataframes. That's just because I am used to thinking about SQL tables. I'm still wrapping my head around how to use the `groupby` object efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above got me going in the right direction. With further work, the following was used. It turns out I needed to use two columns as a compound key to uniquely identify samples.

```
df.header1 = df.header1.fillna(method='ffill')
df.header2 = df.header2.fillna(method='ffill')

grouped = df.groupby(['header1','header2'])

samplelist = []
dfParent = pd.DataFrame()
dfDetail = pd.DataFrame()

for sample, data in grouped:
    samplelist.append(sample)
    dfParent = dfParent.append(grouped.get_group(sample).head(n=1), ignore_index=True)
    dfDetail = dfDetail.append(data[1:], ignore_index=True)

dfParent = dfParent.drop(['header3','header4',etc...]) # remove columns only used in 
                                                       # detail records
dfDetail = dfDetail.drop(['header5','header6',etc...]) # remove columns only used once
                                                       # per sample

# Now details can be extracted by sample number in the sample list 
# (e.g. the first 10 for sample 0)

samplenumber = 0

dfDetail[
    (dfDetail['header1'] == samplelist[samplenumber][0]) &
    (dfDetail['header2'] == samplelist[samplenumber][1])
    ].header3[:10]
```

Useful links were:

[Pandas groupby and get_group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-sorting)

[Pandas append to DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-using-append)